# Windows: How to know when a file is copied, downloaded or executed?

Tags: c#, windows-services, real-time

I'm trying to build a Visual C# application that let's me know when, anywhere in the system, a file is copied, downloaded or executed. Please help.

Comment: The purpose of this site isn't writing code for you.

Comment: Have you had any attempt at the problem? if so, can we see?

Comment: Alex Weitz- I am not asking for the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

1. Create new empty C# application (with IDE of your choice)
2. Read about [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use it
3. Depending of type of notification you wish (email, Telegram, SMS) use corresponding class/library

Comment: Dmitry- I read about that, but what I need is something which doesn't watch a specified directory but the complete system.

Comment: Sahil, take a look at FileMon from SysInternals suite. Their forum (http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic8038_page1.html) says that "file system driver-filter" is used, may be this will help you.